# Android - Get status bar icons

Tags: android, android-notifications, android-notification-bar

For my Android app I need to display all the notification icons that appear on the status bar.
In order to listen for new notifications, I have found the `NotificationListenerService` class, but it's only available for `API >= 18`. Furthermore, it requires the user to let my app have access to their notifications.
So, is there any way (`API < 18`) of getting only the icons for notifications, but without having the user been notified about it?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You must let the user know that you are getting the notifications. This is standard Android behaviour, for security reasons.